# TFS check-in False Positive?

Tags: tfs, tfs-power-tools

This is what I did:

1. Check in a change
2. Roll back change (TFS checks out files and restores original state, but keeps files checked out). good so far.
3. I check in all files to their rolled back state, except web.config.
4. I verify the web.config is how I want it to look and subsequently check it in.

Come in Monday and realize my change is not there.  There's no history on this file except for my rollback.

I'm not ruling out human error, but is there a known issue of false positive check-ins with TFS?

I typically use TFS Power Tools and check in from Explorer (e.g. I like the messagebox that comes back and says "Your Changeset Number is 1000".)

It was a busy day Friday and I don't remember how I checked in (IDE or explorer Power tool).  However, nothing abnormal stands out in my mind with this check-in.

No luck Googling "TFS Known Issues" and "TFS False Positive" so my querying must be off, or it's working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There is no known issue like you describe.

With local workspaces, any changes you made should still be on your system, even if you didn't check them in.